# Arrays display order

Tags: php, mysql

So this script works like this. It takes the tags you have chosen as your interests and compares it with the other users tags. This script below gives me the output of how many tags me and the other person have common.

```
$get_userinfo = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users") or die(mysql_error());
        while($userinfo = mysql_fetch_array($get_userinfo)) {
            $usertags = $userinfo['tags'];
            $tagsdata = explode(" ", $usertags);
            $interestsdata = explode(" ", $interests);
            $result = array_intersect($interestsdata, $tagsdata);
            echo "Count under this belongs to ".$userinfo['name']."";
            echo count($result);
            echo "<br />";
            }
```

Now, I want first, this script also displays me in the list so I see how many tags I have common with myself and I want to remove myself. And second, how do I list it so the person with highest number (most tags common) get displayed at the top and descending.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition to exclude yourself from your own query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id != [your user id]
```

To order by the number of tags, you need to issue an aggregate function in your SQL statement to group results by the tag and user. Without seeing your table structure I can only offer a very generalized statement

```
SELECT username, tag, count(tag) FROM users JOIN tags ON x = y WHERE user_id != [your user id] GROUP BY user_id, tag_id ORDER BY count(tag) DESC
```

Another option is to collect your data, and sort through it with PHP after you already know how many tags each user has in common. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php for information on sorting arrays.

You should also start using PDO or mysqli as the mysql functions have been officially deprecated.

I also *strongly advise* you to not put multiple tags in one database field.

Comment: I'm totally open to change the layout of my database. How should I store the tags do you think?

Comment: Users -> UserTags -> Tags. Many to many relationship. Many users can have many tags. Many Tags can belong to many users. That's an entirely different question though. Maybe ask our friends on the dba stack exchange site.

Comment: So you mean I should make a separate table for tags? But then how do the user then "assign" tags to their self?

Comment: A lookup table. I suggest you read up a bit on MySQL best practices. It will make a huge difference in performance and scalability.